# Smallest integer $n$ such that $\left(1-\frac{n}{365}\right)^n < \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: inequality

Find the smallest integer $n$ such that $$\left(1-\frac{n}{365}\right)^n < \frac{1}{2}.$$

I cannot use a calculator, and I do not know where to begin.

Comment: Do you mean you are not allowed to use a calculator, or do you mean you don't know how to use a calculator, or do you mean you have no access to a calculator?

Comment: I am not allowed to use a calculator.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)?

Comment: you cannot find smallest integer,you can only find smallest positive integer which is $16$ by the way...

Answer (score 5):

To find an integer $n$ such that this holds, rewrite the inequality as $1-(n/365)<\exp(-(\ln2)/n)$ and use the fact that $\exp(-x)>1-x$ for every $x$. Then $n$ will do as soon as
$1-(n/365)<1-(\ln2/n)$, that is, $n^2>365\cdot\ln2$. Since $\ln2<.7$, one knows that $365\cdot\ln2<365\cdot.7=255.5<256=2^8$, hence every $n\geqslant2^4=16$ will do.

The numerical values the reasoning above requires to know to be performed without a calculator are the fact that $\ln2$ is (just) below $.7$ and the first powers of $2$.

It happens that the inequality does not hold for $n=15$ hence $n=16$ is the correct answer but at the moment I do not know how to prove this part without a calculator, except using the (alternating) expansion of the exponential at the second order to lower bound it. This is cumbersome, but here we go.

Since $\exp(-x)<1-x+\frac12x^2$ for every nonnegative $x$, it is enough to check that for $n=15$, $n^2<365\cdot\ln2\cdot(1-\ln2/n)$, which is true if $\ln2>\frac{n}2\left(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{4n}{365}}\right)$. Using $\sqrt{1+x}<1+\frac12x$ for $x=\frac{4n}{365-4n}$ yields $\sqrt{1-\frac{4n}{365}}>\frac{365-4n}{365-2n}$. Hence $\ln2>\frac{n^2}{365-2n}$ is enough, that is, for $n=15$, $\ln2>\frac{45}{67}$. Since $\frac{45}{67}\approx.672$, this proves the thing if one knows that $\ln2$ is greater than $.68$.

The numerical value the reasoning above requires to know to be performed without a calculator is the fact that $\ln2$ is about $.69$.

Comment: Even if we did some careful estimates to show 15 doesn't work, how would that ensure 1-14 don't work either? Something has to be added to justify that.

Comment: Sure, the obvious fact that the sequence of general term $(1-n/N)^n$ is decreasing on $0\leqslant n\leqslant N$, for every fixed positive integer $N$.

Comment: Aaah. Clearly my brain has turned to mush. If you look at my answer below you will see the ridiculous length I went to in order to show an obvious fact!

Comment: @Ragib, yes, I saw that, and I almost wrote a comment in reaction, to mention that differentiation IS a nice tool, pace Leibniz, but NOT the [panacea](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/panacea) students are led to believe it is.

Answer (score 3):

You could get an initial guess, by

$$
\begin{aligned}
   &&\left(1-\frac{n}{365}\right)^n &< \frac{1}{2}.\\
   &\Leftrightarrow & n\ln\left(1-\frac{n}{365}\right) &< -\ln 2\\
\end{aligned}
$$

and using $\ln(1 + x)\approx x$ for small $x$ to arrive at $n\approx \sqrt{365\ln2}$. Then, you'd need to guess a value for this square root, and check if it really meets your requirements.